# compress only new files without zipping again the old ones changing their timestamp

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

Scenario:
on folder1:
we have file1.repo file2.repo file3.repo
after i run this command:

```
/usr/bin/find $folder/*.repo -print -exec sh -c "gzip < {} > {}.gz" \;
```

it will compress all files as file1.repo.gz ,file2.repo.gz, file3.repo.gz

My problem is how i prevent after running more times the command to zip again the same files and just zip only new files added on folder,(the command create again file{1,2,3}.repo.gz with different timestamp and keep original file{1,2,3}.repo on folder too)

what i need is to zip only new files added on folder without zipping again the old files changing their timestamp

Comment: If you can assume, that exactly files ending in `.gz` are zipped, you could tell find to exclude those files. Of course this strategy fails if you would create manually an unzipped file where the name already ends in `.gz`, as this one would then be skipped and stay unzipped.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if `*file1.repo.gz` already exists in the destination and skip if there is.

```
#!/bin/bash

sourceFolder="/path/to/source"
destinationFolder="/path/to/destination"

for f in $( /usr/bin/find $sourceFolder/*.repo ); do
    if ! [ -f "$destinationFolder/*$f*" ]; then
        gzip -c $f > $destinationFolder/$f.gz
    fi
done
```

It looks for every file `*.repo` in a given source folder, then checks if a `*.gz` of it already exists in the destination folder and skips it, if it does; else if `*.gz`'s it into the destination folder.

EDIT: Forgot to set archive name.

Comment: i have problem running script tell me $destinationFolder is a directory on line gzip -c, btw thanks for your help

Comment: Yep, I forgot the variable for the archive name